# blackberry eclipse show device folders

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I am an android programmer but quite newbie using blackberry. How to show device folder structure if using eclipse BB SDK? same as File explorer of android SDK... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry project does not have anything like "device folder structure". There is a file explorer application on the device, that can help you to navigate file/folder on device filesystem.

All applications on BlackBerry are installed to special memory block, it is not a filesystem. It is a closed memory block of internal memory dedicated to installed applications.

It has flat structure, and there are no folders. All files of installed applications have to have unique names. Otherwise new files will replace existing ones.

Also, as you are a newbie, this link will be helpful: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/documentation

Comment: ok, clear, thanks! So, if I do not want to share or show app folder content, should I then hide folder content? Isthis the best practice to reach it?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "app folder content"? On blackberry the installed application does not have dedicated folder. You can embed resources into cod file, and these resources will be installed along with the application.

Comment: understood that has no dedicated folder but I will create custom folders to handle downloaded files. That files will be dynamic so can't be resources. Possible to hide that folders?

Comment: No, there is no way to hide folders neither protect them on the blackberry filesystem. There is an encryption option for the media card, but it encrypts filesystem on the whole media card.